# Company is going to relocate and my commute will double

Tags: united-states, work-life-balance, company-policy

Even more than double taking into account very busy highway near a big city. I'm considering to resign, but I don't want to find myself without unemployment insurance. However I'm not sure about resigning yet - may be the commute won't be that bad.

So, what are my rights and company obligations in this case?

Comment: Any rights and obligations will depend on your country. Where are you located?

Comment: I'm in USA, NJ.

Comment: And is this a doubling from 10 min to 20 min or 1 hour to two hours oh and is your grade/contact a mobile one? By that does the contact say where you work or are you expected to work anywhere reasonable

Comment: Have you actually tried the new commute yet during rush hour to see what it will be like?  If you go via a freeway which has a car pool lane, is there someone near you that you could car pool with?  If not, perhaps you could commute after the car pool line is opened up to everybody (that's what I do).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is United States centric.

In general, companies expect you to move or quit when they relocate. If the move is outside the reasonable commuting area, they generally offer some sort of layoff package. (I am talking here about major moves such as from Boston, MA to Altanta, GA where no daily commute is possible.) However, an hour away may be considered inside the reasonable commuting area and it is likely no package will be offered. I do not think there is any reason why they would be required to offer you anything. I have worked in plenty of companies that moved and only if it was several hundred miles away was a package offered if people did not want to make the new commute.

So likely I would count on there being only two options, make the commute or find another job. It is most likely in your best interests to make the commute in the short-term while you look for another job.

Another option, depending on your position, could be to ask to be allowed to work from home all the time or even one-two days a week.  That could make the long commute more palatable.  We have employees who were in such a situation when we bought their company and they were offered to work from home so they didn't have to commute for an hour and a half.

And of course the final option is to move closer to the new office. Often you can get out of a lease if your workplace has moved.

Comment: I've personally been through this myself, expect I had recently bought a house, in such cases relocation isn't really a viable option, in those cases you just decide... Make the commute or find a new job. (as far as allowing for a severance package of sorts, I haven't heard of this before, but I also live in FL where employees aren't treated as well as many places in the US in general... as always exceptions apply)

Comment: The middle paragraph here is probably the best course of action. Suffer through the new commute whilst looking for another job.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you have any legal grounds here nor would I be qualified to tell you either way.

You could use this as an opportunity to ask to work remotely (some or full time). Even if companies don't do this normally, you could be a good test. Sometimes it is the risk of losing a current employee that makes them consider this option. I've done this several times when I relocated away from the company. If you've been there for a few years and are considered a key employee, your odds are better.

Otherwise, I think you should look for another job and suck up the commute in the mean time. I don't think you should quit.

Comment: @DIY Also ask for flexible hours.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything rash, evaluate your choices and carefully pick what's best for you. In your evaluation you consider that moving is inconvenient, a long commute is inconvenient, finding a new job is inconvenient, and being without a job is very inconvenient. You also need to check that this move isn't just a ruse to make employees quit before a company is going to be shut down, although that would be more likely with a much further move.

I'd expect the company to lose some employees, so your position will be stronger, so if you are willing to change companies you could at least try to extract a raise or working some days from home from that change. (If you were not willing to change companies it would be worth a try as well). If you are successful, that might fix your problem.

If that doesn't work, resigning is obviously the wrong thing to do. The right thing to do is actively looking for a new job, and giving your notice when you signed a contract with the new company. You might think about not keeping your job search secret, because you could try to extract a raise or some days working from home (see above). Usually you wouldn't tell your company that you are looking for a new job, but in this case it should be obvious to everyone that you are not at all unhappy with your job, but you just want some compensation for the longer commute.

Moving usually involves considerable cost and inconvenience. I'd only consider that if moving actually improves your living conditions (for example you can move to a nicer location, or it is closer to your spouse's workplace as well), and if I were either convinced that the job at the new location is safe, or if there are other well-paying jobs in the new area.

PS. Asking for flexible hours, as others suggested, can be very effective. Depending on traffic, working 8 to 5 might mean two hours commute each way, while working 10 to 7 might take less than an hour. It's an example where an employer can give tons of benefits to the employee at very little or zero cost; the way how the employer reacts to that suggestion would also tell you something about the company that could guide other decisions.

Comment: "*a ruse to make employees quit before a company is going to be shut down*" - any reason for the company to do that?

Comment: Depends on the country. If you want to shut a place down, you might have to pay compensation to the workers. So you move the company to some remote place, you save paying compensation to everyone who quits, and three months later you shut down anyway. I know people who had that fine experience (fortunately I left earlier).

Comment: What kind of compensation? I don't have anything about severance pay in my contract. And unemployment compensation is paid by state, right?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in the US as you question unemployment insurance. Companies can move. They have no obligation to their employees with regard to commute time. Unemployment varies state to state. Some states are more lenient than others, but if you resign what the state considers is a perfectly good job, you are probably reducing your chances of getting unemployment insurance.

Have you considered moving?

Comment: The company relocation might be temporary, so I consider moving as a last option