# Company relocating, can I qualify for unemployment?

Tags: resignation

Company relocating within NJ. Commute distance will be 62 miles each way along 2 major highways with heavy congestion during rush hours. Can I collect unemployment if I quit?

Comment: This is a legal question, not suitable for this site.

Comment: Some relevant answers here, but ultimately this question is off-topic: [Company is going to relocate and my commute will double](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33420/company-is-going-to-relocate-and-my-commute-will-double)

Comment: Mass transit?  While 62 miles would probably drive me nuts.  I know a fair number of people who commute two hours each way, so not sure it would be considered unreasonable when deemed as a cause for losing your job.

Answer (score 2):

http://work.chron.com/can-collect-unemployment-employer-relocates-12921.html

I believe you should clarify what would constitute 'cause' if you're not being laid off by your employer. I think this is a question you might want to ask an employment lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get a lay-off notice from your employer, your chances of qualifying for unemployment is very slim to none.

On the other hand, you may try telling your employer that you do not want to work from NJ facility and they might show you the door. But again this might be a termination with cause (insubordination, in other words, not following orders from superiors, comes to mind) if they really want to make it so.

Your best bet is to ask this in a [legal forum](http://forum.freeadvice.com/hiring-firing-wrongful-termination-5/), unless you want to spend money to consult with an employment lawyer.