# My company is looking to move, but some employees want to stay

Tags: offices, location

The employer is looking to move offices, however, some of the employees, myself included, wish to stay in this office due to ease of commute. This move is not due to size or difference in rent, the move is being considered so that the company is in a trendier neighborhood.  Can/how can I go about pushing back on the move?

Comment: Related question, not a duplicate: [Company is going to relocate and my commute will double](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33420/company-is-going-to-relocate-and-my-commute-will-double)

Comment: *the move is being considered* - How did you hear about it if they haven't made the decision yet? Are they actively seeking feedback from employees?

Comment: @BSMP no just we have a lot of transparency with the business' decisions

Comment: @WorkerDrone NYC

Comment: What kind of office is this?  How does being in a trendier neighborhood affect the company's bottom line?  It can mean "omg, this is stupid" to "wow, yeah, this is going to boost sales a lot".

Comment: @Nelson were a software consultancy, so take that how you will.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't.

The company can move wherever it wants. Period.

You can try to convince them it will hurt morale.

You can try to convince them that it will increase turnover.

You can even threaten to quit either individually or collectively.

Ultimately, the company will do what it chooses to do.

Comment: It's worth noting that sometimes moves like this are an easy way to clear out certain people from a company.

Comment: @NotMe: Exactly. Mostly the ones who are competent and have no problem finding a job elsewhere. You keep the ones that are afraid of losing their job and finding nothing elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can prevent the move. So you have a choice. Move and perhaps get some compensation for the addition mileage or get another job

Comment: Yep, stuff like this definitely leaves room to negotiate some things. Were my current employer to move downtown or across town, my commute would be about 4 to 6 times longer than it currently is, so I'd definitely ask for a wage increase to offset the added cost of gas and the need for more regular maintenance (oil changes, etc.) If they're feeling particularly bold they could even ask to adjust their work schedule to accommodate traffic.